# How do/ can I print an arrays contents into a textView in Android Studios Kotlin

Tags: arrays, android-studio, kotlin, textview

lets say I'm making a simple dnd dice roller (cause I am), I get results and I turn it into an array.
Now I want to print the results of the array into a textView that would say:
randNumResultsDisplay.text = "Rolled " then it would spit out all results in the array, in order that they were put in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure where you are stuck here, but if you want to convert an array into a String, one option is to use the `java.utils.Arrays` class:

```kotlin
val myArray = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val contents = Arrays.toString(myArray)
println(contents) // prints "[1, 2, 3]"
```

So to inject that in your text view as you suggested:

```kotlin
randNumResultsDisplay.text = "Rolled ${Arrays.toString(yourValuesArray)}"
```

That being said, you would get it for free if you used `List` instead of `Array` (which is very much advised):

```kotlin
randNumResultsDisplay.text = "Rolled $yourList"
```

Another option as pointed out in the comments is the [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) method, which works on both arrays and lists and allows you to customize the formatting:

```kotlin
println("Rolled: ${myArray.joinToString()}")
// Rolled 1, 2, 3

println("Rolled: ${myArray.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]")}")
// Rolled [1, 2, 3]

println("Rolled: ${myArray.joinToString(separator = "|")}")
// Rolled 1|2|3
```

Comment: You probably want ``joinToString`` in this case since you get more control over the formatting, so ``println("Rolled: ${myArray.joinToString(", ")}")`` will give you nice output (and you can get fancy with it)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I tried something very similar, but it didn't work. This worked great tho.